# ReactiveTable pagination change meteor

Tags: meteor

How to change the Meteor Reactive tables pagination? We have done the sample code for this.

```
<div id="table">
    {{> reactiveTable collection=api_key settings=tableSettings class="table table-bordered table-hover"}}
</div>
```

Comment: What you tried? DId you refereed to official documentation? and what you want to change here?

Comment: We see the documentation in that they provide the sample pagenation. Like showing the previous and next buttons.But i need the pagenation like this  prev 123456 next.@ajduke